# Leanback library - PlaybackSupportFragment - how to hide secondary actions

Tags: java, android, android-tv, leanback

I'm working on an Android TV app that plays a video and I'm using PlaybackSupportFragment to implement the on-screen controls.
I am, however, not able to fully hide the secondary actions (thumbs up, thumbs down, repeat, ...). Actually I was able to hide the buttons, however the "three dots" button still stays there. And I have not figured out how to hide this "three dots" button.

I tried not to add any secondary actions buttons. But no luck. There are no secondary buttons but the "three-dots" button is still there.

```java
public class MySupportFragment extends PlaybackSupportFragment {
  MyPlaybackControlGlue myGlue = new MyPlaybackControlGlue(context);
  ...
  myGlue.setHost(new PlaybackSupportFragmentGlueHost(this));
  ...
}

public class MyPlaybackControlGlue extends PlaybackControlGlue{
  ...
  @Override
  protected void onCreateSecondaryActions(ArrayObjectAdapter adapter) {
    //Do not add any secondary actions to the adapter
  }
  @Override
  protected void onCreatePrimaryActions(SparseArrayObjectAdapter adapter) {
        //No need to add any other actions here. The Play/Pause action is enough.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.
Do not add any secondary actions in the "onCreateSecondaryActions" method.
But also call following method so that the "three dots" button is not shown.
`getControlsRowPresenter().setSecondaryActionsHidden(false)`

For example like so

```
@Override
protected  void onCreateControlsRowAndPresenter() {
    super.onCreateControlsRowAndPresenter();
    getControlsRowPresenter().setSecondaryActionsHidden(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that have you posted in the question worked for me, however I am extending VideoPlayerGlue

```
public class CustomPlaybackControlGlue extends VideoPlayerGlue {
    public CustomPlaybackControlGlue(Context context, LeanbackPlayerAdapter playerAdapter, OnActionClickedListener actionListener) {
        super(context, playerAdapter, actionListener);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreatePrimaryActions(ArrayObjectAdapter adapter) {
        //Do not add any secondary actions to the adapter
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreateSecondaryActions(ArrayObjectAdapter adapter) {
        //No need to add any other actions here. The Play/Pause action is enough.
    }
}
```